# Problem Customizing People Refinement Panel

Tags: people-search

I am creating a web part page that uses People Search Core Results and People Refinement Panel to display our People Search in table view. ***The problem I am having is that my People Refinement Panel will only show the default Filter Category Definition despite it being changed and Use Default Configuration being unchecked.***

What could be causing this to happen? How can I fix it?

*Please note: Mapped properties are already setup and full crawl was ran. Also, they are setup to be used in scopes.*

Answer (score 0):

Found something that worked for me. I deleted my People Search Core Results webpart and then put it back in. After that the Refinement Panel showed my changes.

I guess the Refinement Panel needed to be setup/configured before the People Search Core Results webpart is used in a page.